# Need to get data between two dates in SQL

Tags: sql, laravel

I need to get data between two dates. here, I have added simple example as below :
Ihave added below logic in my SQL query but not working, pls help me :

like If MyDate = 2020-07-09 15:15:00

I have to run cron job. So, get those type data which datas MyDate between date of 12 hours ago and date of pending 1 hour to complete MyDate.

Pls help me to get idea using Mysql queries.

[image: Show data 12hoursand1hourago_of_enddate]

I tried this one but not getting data :
`SELECT  * FROM test WHERE ENDDATE BETWEEN (ENDDATE - INTERVAL 12 HOUR) AND (ENDDATE - INTERVAL 1 HOUR) ORDER BY ENDDATE DESC;`

Comment: you should show us what you have tried so far. Then we can help you

Comment: Show your code, so we can help

Comment: Okay i will edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys, I got the Solution from MyEnd as below :

SELECT  * FROM test WHERE ( now() > (ENDDATE - INTERVAL 12 HOUR) AND now() <= (ENDDATE - INTERVAL 1 HOUR)) ORDER BY ENDDATE DESC;

Answer (score 0):

look into whereBetween

```
whereBetween('reservation_from', [$from1, $to1])
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses